# Shell Script to verify root pw

Tags: linux, bash, passwords

I have a script that adds users to a linux system. I was intending to have a step that sets the root pw to a default but how can I do this without having that pw in cleartext in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `usermod`'s option "-p" in the manpage:

```
-p, --password PASSWORD

  The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).

  Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted
  password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

  The password will be written in the local /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow file.
  This might differ from the password database configured in your PAM
  configuration. You should make sure the password respects the system's
  password policy.
```

Comment: So would I run openssl on my current clear text password and then use the encrypted version in my script using -p ?

Comment: Run `openssl passwd` once and use the encrypted password with `usermod -p`.

Comment: Thanks - can't someone then just take the encrypted pw out of the shell script and use openssl to decrypt it back to its original form?

Comment: Not with openssl. Protect your script the way /etc/shadow is protected and force your user to change password at first login.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to have your script write the new user info to a file.  Then, have another script (executed by root) which actually adds the new users using the useradd command.  Perhaps the second script can be a cron job that runs every couple of minutes.  It wouldn't be in real time, but I would feel better about the security of doing it this way, rather than having a root password in a public-facing script.